# Open source client portal software?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, development, software

I'd like to provide my clients a portal to view status, mockups, links to resources, etc...  I don't need anything terribly complex, but I would rather grab something that's already out there than write it myself right now (plenty of client work to do!).

Any ideas?  Suggestions?

Edit: Web development for fairly small busineeses.  These are typically 3-6 month projects with 2-3 iterations per month.  It's really just to demonstrate progress in an orderly fashion.

Comment: You'll need to give us more information as to what business you are in. Status of what? Mockups of what?

Answer (score 1):

I've considered building something like this in the past, but I ultimately came to the conclusion that displaying mockups and getting client feedback/approvals is best done through a project manager to streamline the workflow, and many project management apps will allow you to do this, including:

- [OpenAtrium](http://openatrium.org) - strictly speaking, OA is an intranet/team portal, but it also includes project management functionality as well as a blog feature that can be used for discussions and posting mockups for feedback). OA is built on Drupal, so if you have Drupal development experience, you should be able to tweak it to your needs very easily.
- [ManyMoon](http://manymoon.com) (now do.com) - this is a freemium project management app that integrates with Gmail, Google Calendar, Google Docs and Google Tasks. It's very simple and straightforward to use, and as a project manager, it's one of the best I've come across for interacting with clients.
- [Asana](http://asana.com) - This is a free project management app developed by some people from Facebook. It's based on a dashboard interface which, while more complicated than ManyMoon, is a lot more efficient (at least before MM's revamp) for collaborating in a team. It may be slightly more difficult for clients to learn than ManyMoon, but I personally prefer Asana's single-dashboard interface to the old ManyMoon interface.

Answer (score 0):

I found these 2 scripts (and your question) while researching the same thing:

- [Advanced Client Portal](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-client-portal/113198)
- [Ultimate Client Manager](http://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-client-manager/47626)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not opensource ,nor free, but the first thing that pops in my mind is [basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a project management tool written by web development company. It is called [todoyou](http://www.todoyu.com/). It is maybe a little bit more than what you need but it is worth to check it out.